# Is there a website that compares both Scopus and WoS (SCI/E)' ranks of a journal/publication altogether?

Tags: journals, website, indexing, scopus, web-of-science

Something like [Resurchify](https://www.resurchify.com/impact/details/24807), but contains both Scopus and Web of Science, perhaps?

I usually just browse separately on https://www.scimagojr.com/ (for Scopus) and https://jcr.clarivate.com (for SCI/E / Web of Science) to find the rank of a journal. But lately browsing on Clarivate has been a hassle for me (slow loading, always get redirected, requires an institutional login which I don't have access to, hence I haven't been able to find the information that I need).

I am wondering whether there is a website/integrated platform to browse for the latest ranks more conveniently? Any feedback on how to get SCI/E info would also be appreciated. Thank you.

Note: My main field is computer engineering and computer science.

Comment: Ask your preferred library if they have access to the Journal Citation Reports from WoS. The latest useful rank are the latest published ranks, they are published once per year.